# Creating specific rule in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, rules

We recently changed our company name so our email domain has changed.  How do I set a rule to send a reply (Template message) to only people using my old email address? I don't want them to get it if they are using the new one.  The message is to inform them of the email address change.

Comment: This might gives a hint to the corect answer: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/404336-outlook-rules-based-on-email-address-alias-sent-to.

Answer (score 0):

These instructions are for Microsoft Outlook 2016 (not the Office 365 Outlook). It should be fairly easy to adjust these rules for any version of Outlook back to Outlook 2010.

1. From the **HOME** tab, pull down **RULES** and select **Create Rule...**
2. Click on **Advanced Options...**
3. Select the condition "with specific words in the recipient's address"
4. This condition will appear in the rule description below. In the rule description, click on the highlighted "selected words".
5. In the **Search Text** dialog that appears, in the first field, enter the old email address, or enough of it to ensure that it will trigger on that and only that, then click on **Add...**, then click on **OK**
6. You'll return to the Rule Wizard. Click **Next >**
7. You will now be selecting an action. The action you want is "reply using a specific template".
8. Select the template. You will need to have created the template and saved it earlier. Once it's selected, click **NEXT >**
9. Select any exceptions, and edit the criteria as needed, then click **Next >**
10. Give the rule a name, and click **FINISH**. The rule is now ready to run, and will run the next time someone sends you a message to the specified address.